# Auto_increment in oracle

Tags: oracle, auto-increment

I am student

i doing assignement , do `auto increment`

How to create an `auto increment`  in Oracle ?

```
CREATE TABLE mua_thi
( 
 mamuathi varchar2(10) not null,
 check(mamuathi like 'MT%')
)
 mamuathi = MT + auto_increment;


create or replace trigger tangmuathi
before insert or update
on mua_thi

begin 
set new.mamuathi := MT + muathitang.nextval from Dual;
end;

create sequence muathitang start 
with 1 increment by 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mamuathi = MT + auto_increment;
```

Don't structure your table like that.  That's a smart key (a single string with several components concatenated).  Smart keys are dumb.  If the "MT" is crucial (why have a key with a hardcoded, unchanging element?) make it a separate column.

```
CREATE TABLE mua_thi ( mamuathi varchar2(2) not null
                       , id number (8) not null 
                       , primary key (mamuathi, id )
                       , check(mamuathi = 'MT')
  );
```

Actually there's still some bad practice there.  One, name the constraints - it makes life easier:

```
, constraint mt_pk primary key (mamuathi, id )
, constraint mt_ck check(mamuathi = 'MT')
```

Two, if `mamuathi` is genuinely a constant it's pointless using it in the key:

```
, constraint mt_pk primary key ( id )
```

Three,  `mamuathi` may evolve to several values , so think about whether a foreign key to a look-up table might be better.

Obviously the drawback to splitting a smart key is the need to refrence multiple columns.  In 11g we can use the virtual column feature to avoid that inconveience:

```
CREATE TABLE mua_thi ( mamuathi varchar2(2) not null
                       , id number (8) not null 
                       , mamuathi_disp AS mamuathi||lpad(id,8,'0')
                       , primary key (mamuathi, id )
                       , check(mamuathi = 'MT')
  );
```